# jquery .keyup event on input not firing

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to have a simple addition calculation when an input is keyup'ed. Here is my html:

```
<tr id="a">
        <td>
            <label>A</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>Results/Action Orientation (asset)</label>
        </td>
        <td class="shade">
            <input id="a_per" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td class="shade">
            <input id="a_pot" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td class="shade">
            <input id="a_tot" class="totals" type="text" disabled="disabled" />
        </td>
</tr>
```

And here is my jQuery for the keyup event:

```
$('#a_per').keyup(function() {
    if($('#a_pot').value != "") {
        var tot = this.value + $('#a_pot').value;
        $('#a_tot').value = tot;
    }
});
```

I am going to tailor it to fire when either #a_per or #a_pot keyup but first I want to make sure this will work.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another alternative:

```
$('#a_per,#a_pot').keyup(function() {
  var a_per = +$('#a_per').val() || 0;
  var a_pot = +$('#a_pot').val() || 0;
  $('#a_tot').val(a_per + a_pot);
});​
```

[A working example](http://jsfiddle.net/9uDRC/1/).

Comment: Wouldn't this still need casting to int/float?

Comment: You could say this *autocast* itself. Being honest I think it is the better answer.

Comment: I am not a javascript/jQuery expert so excuse my ignorance. What are the advantages of this method over those listed above? If it is more efficient I will use it. It isn't as readable as the above examples though.

Comment: You would like to read [How do I Convert a String into an Integer in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript)

Comment: Will do, thanks for the advice and help. I have been looking at your answer more and agree with you now. I didn't notice all that was going on. I am switching yours to the answer. Thanks again. :)

Comment: I added a little trick to prevent `NaN`, even though the best thing would be to to check `$('#a_pot').val() !== ""`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your use of .value to .val(). You'll also want to apply parseFloat or parseInt to your addition function, otherwise you'll end up concatenating strings. Also wrap `this` is jQuery tags like:

```
$('#a_per').keyup(function() {
    if($('#a_pot').val() != "") {
        var tot = parseFloat($(this).val()) + parseFloat($('#a_pot').val());
        $('#a_tot').val(tot);
    }
});​
```

Comment: Awesome! This fixed it. I will set to answer once stackoverflow lets me. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: No problem. You may also want to consider checking for non-numeric input.

Comment: I will be adding validation to it yet. I switched over to parseInt as I will not be accepting any floats. I assume that parseInt is faster than parseFloat, although it would probably not be noticable.

Comment: Not noticeable by much. When using parseInt, make sure you add the radix parameter. E.g. `parseInt($(this).val(),10)`.

Comment: Forgot about that. Thanks. Set to answer now.

Answer (score 1):

use `val()`, not value.

```
$(function(){

   $('#a_per').keyup(function() {
     var item=$(this);

      if(item.val() != "") {
         var tot = parseInt(item.val()) + parseInt($('#a_pot').val());
         $('#a_tot').val(tot);
      }
   });

});
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/zzS3U/9/